# Hibernate lazy loading not working many-to-one XML

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazily load a collection in Hibernate. From what I've read this is the best practice way to do this:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Hibernate.initialize(this.truckReviews);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
return this.truckReview;
```

However, when I run this unit test, the assertion fails:

```
Truck realTruck = Truck.getTruckByID(1);
TruckReview realFakeReview = new TruckReview();
realFakeReview.setTruck(realTruck);
realFakeReview.setUser(IntegrationTestResources.getTestUser());
realFakeReview.setReviewDate(new Date());
realFakeReview.setReviewStars(5);
realFakeReview.setReviewText("fake review");
realFakeReview.save();
assertTrue(realTruck.loadReviews().contains(realFakeReview));
realFakeReview.delete();
```

Needless to say, I'm a bit confused since other StackOverflow threads say this is the way to do it properly. I feel like I must be missing something very obvious but I'm still new to Hibernate and have no idea what.

Here's the mapping file for this class:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="edu.temple.tutrucks.Truck" table="truck" catalog="TUTrucks" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="truckName" type="string">
        <column name="truck_name" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="latitude" type="double">
        <column name="latitude" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="longitude" type="double">
        <column name="longitude" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="openingTime" type="imm_time">
        <column name="opening_time" not-null="false"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="closingTime" type="imm_time">
        <column name="closing_time" not-null="false"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="avatar" type="string">
        <column name="avatar"></column>
    </property>
    <list name="truckReviews" table="truck_review" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="truck_id" />
        </key>
        <list-index column="review_stars" />
        <one-to-many class="edu.temple.tutrucks.TruckReview" />
    </list>
    <list name="menus" table="menu" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="truck_id" />
        </key>
        <list-index column="id" />
        <one-to-many class="edu.temple.tutrucks.Menu" />
    </list>
    <set name="tags" table="tag_truck_map" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="truck_id" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many column="tag_id" class="edu.temple.tutrucks.Tag"></many-to-many>
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Still having issues, I've changed the loadReviews method to this

```
@Override
public Truck loadReviews() { // lazy loading needs to be fixed
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Truck retval = (Truck) session.get(Truck.class, this.getId());
    Hibernate.initialize(retail.getTruckReviews());
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    retval.truckReviews.size();
    return retval;
}
```

And the test now looks like this

```
@Test
public void testloadReviews() {
    Truck realTruck = Truck.getTruckByID(1, false, false);
    TruckReview realFakeReview = new TruckReview();
    realFakeReview.setTruck(realTruck);
    realFakeReview.setUser(IntegrationTestResources.getTestUser());
    realFakeReview.setReviewDate(new Date());
    realFakeReview.setReviewStars(5);
    realFakeReview.setReviewText("fake review");
    realFakeReview.save();
    assertTrue(realTruck.loadReviews().getTruckReviews().contains(realFakeReview));
    realFakeReview.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't to use `realTruck` form one session to do `Hibernate.initialize(this.truckReviews)` using other session

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
// you need to reload persistent with 
// realTruck = session.get(), realTruck = session.load() here
Hibernate.initialize(this.getTruckReviews());
```

You need to use a getter not a property, because of Hibernate need to have a proxy. A proxy is returned by a getter

```
Hibernate.initialize(this.getTruckReviews());
```

Comment: I've made some changes to reflect your advice but I'm still having the same issues. Any ideas?

Comment: still having issues, made another update using the getters instead of the properties but it's still not working.

Comment: @NickDell'osa `realTruck.loadReviews().getTruckReviews()` if this line doesn't produce an exception, the collection is loaded. An assertion is failed, because of `contains()` uses `equals()`. You need to override `equals()`.

Comment: It was another issue that was causing the collection not to loaded. I have since resolved this issue. However, now I'm having issues with a different, but related test, where Hibernate is pulling a bunch of nulls in between actual data.

Comment: @NickDell'osa `initialize()` works. nulls can be produced by  joins, don't know.

Comment: I fixed it by switching from a list to a bag. Thanks for all your help!